# Filter html table with both input and select boxes

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to modify this existing code which currently filters a html table based on multiple inputs, so that it also filters on all select boxes?

I initially tried changing the querySelectorAll('input') to document.querySelectorAll('input, select'), however this broke other parts of the code.

```
  const query = q => document.querySelectorAll(q);
  
  const filters = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input')).map(e => new RegExp(e.value, 'i'));

  query('tbody tr').forEach(row => row.style.display = 
    filters.every((f, i) => f.test(row.cells[i + 1].textContent)) ? '' : 'none');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: I have a table with two input search fields and one two dropdown filters, so I am trying to modify the querySelectorAll to incorporate both input fields and select fields. currently the code above only works for the two input fields.

Comment: Can you post an example of your HTML markup? Perhaps it's an issue with your structure.

Also, just because what you tried broke something else doesn't mean that it was wrong. It just means that it exposed issues elsewhere.

Comment: please find mockup here: https://codepen.io/alfish/pen/OJRwGYb?editors=1010. I am trying to add the select box for airframe into the filter also.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated. I still can't manage to figure this out.